# Should CSS update when JavaScript changes element attributes?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some buttons, and in javascript I do some manipulation. Depending on what the user clicks, buttons will be enabled and disabled.

The logic and the enabling/disabling works well.  But my css isn't updating the look of a disabled button.  I think my question is, should it automatically update?  Or do I need to handle that somehow?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC if that is relevant.

I simply added this to the top of my view (for testing) :

```
<style>
   button[disabled] {
       background: green;
   }
</style>
```

and a snippet of the javascript :

```
function changeNameEnabled(enabled) {
    document.getElementsByName("FullNameExact")[0].disabled = !enabled;
}
```

a sample button:

```
<button onclick="nameClick(this)" name="FullNameExact" style="height:20%;width:75%;top:5%;left:13%;margin-bottom:5%">FULL NAME EXACT</button>
```

and I can see in the browser that the button gains the `disabled` attribute, and is unclickable

Comment: It should update automatically. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: It should update. So there is something wrong if it doesn't.

Comment: try `button[disabled="disabled"]`
Or maybe
`button:disabled `
one of those selectors should work im sure

Comment: I've actually tried that, and `[disabled=true]` and a few others with the same result

Comment: what browser are you using? not all browsers support that kind of selectors

Comment: currently in google chrome

Comment: well since you're not showing the entire code i can only assume your code doesnt properly disable the button, for example your button is calling the nameClick function and you function is named changeNameEnabled i assume there is more code to it, so either post it for further help or there isnt so much more i can tell

Comment: Do you have a demo of this not working?

Comment: Are you sure `enabled` is either `false` or `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jht2/1/

I made your code usable in a fiddle. What you were doing is passing an DOM element to a function by using this in an onclick attribute:

```
<button onclick="nameClick(this)" name="FullNameExact" style="height:20%;width:75%;top:5%;left:13%;margin-bottom:5%">FULL NAME EXACT</button>
```

So when the function is called, it will try to invert a DOM element. And error.

Even if you set the `disabled` attribute to a boolean it won't work. You will need to use toString on a boolean or any string, even 'a' or 'foo'.

And here everything works. Hope it'll help.

Tip: don't use the onclick attribute. Instead, use the DOM event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to the button when disabling it? The CSS will automatically be applied when the class is added.

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

In general, for managing the classes in javascript:
[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score -3):

button[disabled] wont work , better add some .disabled class , then it will work out.